# Error while checking the login in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

*My function to open a database is as follows, and this to open the database

```
    function opendb()
    {

      $db_info['host'] ='localhost';
      $db_info['user'] ='root';
      $db_info['password'] ='';
      $db_info['db'] ='admin';
      if( $GLOBALS["DBC"]=mysql_connect($db_info['host'],$db_info['user'],$db_info['password']))
      {
        if($r=mysql_select_db($db_info['db'],$GLOBALS["DBC"]))
        {
          mysql_set_charset('utf8',$GLOBALS["DBC"]);
          return;
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Error opening database ".$db_info['db'];
          closedb();
          exit;
        }

      }
      else
      {
        echo "Impossible to connect to the SQL server";
        exit;
      }
      return;
    }
```

*And here the php function to check the login which is passed by the user

```
    function checklogin($email,$pwd)
    {
        opendb();
      $s="select * from users where email='".$email."' and pwd=md5('".$pwd."')";
      $x=mysql_query($s);

      if(mysql_num_rows($x)>0)
      {
        $r=mysql_fetch_array($x);
        closedb();
        return(true);
      }
      else
      {
        closedb();
       return(false);
      }
    }
```

*The thing is , when i enter correct details it is always showing the error message.in the index page i wrote the code as follows . The problem is its always showing the error message and not validating the login password and username that entered.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{

  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
  $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
  if(checklogin($email,$password))
  {
    $url="Location: admin.php";
    header($url);

  }
  else
  {
    $error="Wrong Email or Password";
  }
}
```

please help me on this. Many Thanks

Comment: Can we have `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($x))`?

Comment: Firstly stop using deprecated `mysql_*` function instead start using `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: What's your error if you can't figure then use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: there is no error showing and  the problem is jumping out from checking the datas in the table

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $result=mysql_fetch_array($x); instead of $r=mysql_fetch_array($x); and return(true);
I think $r is a local variable to the function.
Maybe try adding something like this to your function:

```
$x = mysql_query($s);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($x)){ 
    foreach($r AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
    $theusername = $r['theusername'];
    $thepassword = $r['thepassword'];
    echo $theusername;
}
```

Comment: I've added some test code above to help see what's going on.

Comment: in the checklogin function, temporarily echo $s and then manually cut and paste it into mysql to see the output or error response.